# Retrieving the values assigned to NOT x from a given string?

Tags: python, list

I tried creating a regex that I can use to extract out the values assigned to variable x, which is preceded by "NOT" in the following string:

```
(req.idf=6ca9a AND (req.ster=201 OR req.ster=st_home) AND (req.ste=hi OR req.ster=hijst_iuer OR ((req.ster=laHome OR req.ster=laHome_Jtre) AND (tax=IN OR taxIP=MX))) AND NOT x=3422 AND (NOT (x=u259 OR x=1132 OR x=1144))AND NOT (x=28743 or x=09323 or x=12323) AND (x=113323 OR x=90323 OR x=1112123)
```

I am trying to get the output in the following format, by getting the numerical values assigned to the variable followed by NOT x: [3422, 1132, 1144, 28743, 09323, 12323]

So far, I have tried creating regex like:

```
(?:(?:NOT\s*x=)|(?:NOTx=))(\d+)
```

which can only fetch the value for 3422. [It fetches the numerical values assigned to the "NOT x=" or "NOTx=" string before the "x="]

I am trying to achieve the above parsing task programmatically, to also include the instances where I can retrieve the numerical values assigned to x, where NOT is followed by parenthesis, and within the opening "(" and ")" and there are multiple assignments to the variable "x" inside the parenthesis.
Some examples:

```
x= 3424 AND NOT (x=34343 OR x=1214 OR x=11121 AND (x=23232 OR x=1121))
```

In this case, the logic should retrieve the values : [34343, 1214, 11121, 23232, 1121]

In summary, I am trying to achieve:

1. Whenever "NOT" is detected in the string, check if the following character is "x=" or " x=" . If "x=" or " x=" is present, find the numerical value assigned to variable "x" and add it to a list "result".
2. Whenever "NOT" is detected in the string, check if the following character is a "(" or " (" and then for every occurrence of "x=" or " x=" until a matching ")"  is found for the staring “(” , find the numerical value assigned to variable "x" and add it to a list "result" List item.

My code so far:

```
def extract_not_x(target):
    result = []
    i = 0
    while i < len(target):
        if target[i:i+3] == "NOT":
            i += 3
            if i < len(target) and (target[i:i+2] == "x=" or target[i:i+3] == " x="):
                i += 2 if target[i+1] == "=" else 3
                j = i
                while j < len(target) and target[j].isdigit():
                    j += 1
                result.append(int(target[i:j]))
                i = j
            elif i < len(target) and (target[i:i+2] == "( " or target[i] == "("):
                i += 1
                while i < len(target) and target[i] != ")":
                    if target[i:i+2] == "x=" or target[i:i+3] == " x=":
                        i += 2 if target[i+1] == "=" else 3
                        j = i
                        while j < len(target) and target[j].isdigit():
                            j += 1
                        result.append(int(target[i:j]))
                        i = j
                    else:
                        i += 1
                i += 1
        else:
            i += 1
    return result

print(extract_not_x("(req.idf=6ca9a AND (req.ster=201 OR req.ster=st_home) AND (req.ste=hi OR req.ster=hijst_iuer OR ((req.ster=laHome OR req.ster=laHome_Jtre) AND (tax=IN OR taxIP=MX))) AND NOT x=3422 AND (NOT (x=u259 OR x=1132 OR x=1144))AND NOT (x=28743 or x=09323 or x=12323) AND (x=113323 OR x=90323 OR x=1112123)"))
```

The code only retrieves the result as `[3422]`

The expectation is : `[3422, 1132, 1144, 28743, 09323, 12323]`

Comment: Regular expressions are not approprpriate for trying to match balanced parentheses. Use a recursive descent parser.

Comment: @Barmar, Thanks for your response, I haven't worked with the descent parser before, is there any resource I can refer for my use case.

Comment: Recursive descent parsing is not trivial, it's a major component of a compiler class.

Comment: Where does the string come from?  Is it in some known format? Perhaps there's already a library that exists to parse it.